# How to insert more than 2 queries in MySQL using arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I have a problem in inserting query in MySQL. Whenever I try to submit more than 2 queries in MySQL. Like this:

[image]

The first 2 queries(2011 and 2012) will only be inserted to MySQL. While the 2013 was not inserted. I'm sorry but I'm just new here in PHP. I want the forms to be submitted and inserted all the queries to MySQL. I want that whenever I try to input more than two forms that it will be all submitted and inserted to MySQL and not just 2 queries only.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','sample');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$i = 0;

foreach ($_REQUEST as $val) {
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

$year = $_REQUEST['field_name'][$i];

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year) VALUES ('$year')");
$i++;
} 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add more fields using jQuery</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a     href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img     src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
    }
});
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button     is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
input[type="text"]{height:20px; vertical-align:top;}
.field_wrapper div{ margin-bottom:10px;}
.add_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.remove_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-    bottom;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form name="codexworld_frm" action="" method="post">
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is better to do one insert query that hitting the database several time. Now you only have a couple of entries, but think about a case where you have millions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this code,

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $val) {
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

$year = $_REQUEST['field_name'][$i];

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year) VALUES ('$year')");
$i++;
}
```

Use this code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && isset($_REQUEST['field_name'])) {
  foreach ($_REQUEST['field_name'] as $val) {
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year) VALUES ('$val')");
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

You are only ing the value of `field_name`, so loop over it.

No need for increment counter.

Comment: for first loop you need use `for` not `foreach`, because you need increment `$i` and you `foreach $_REQUEST` but get `REQUEST['field_name']` don using `$val` this error!

Comment: @Naumov, please read the program once again. And if possible, try to run it on your machine. Its not mandatory to use OP's logic for answering. The answer should work, that is the criteria.

Comment: There is no need of `for`. The program will become complex unnecessarily.

Comment: you can simple bind parameters as array to query for multiinsert https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html. sorry I don't understand finaly your answer I can up vote

Comment: Yes, we do it. Its a different approach. I gave the answer with my little knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    for($i=0;$i<=count($_REQUEST);$i++){
    $year = $_REQUEST['field_name'][$i];
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year) VALUES ('$year')");
}
```

Comment: have you tries this?

Comment: i tried your code and than after i put solution here.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use one query, Take two query's and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$newdata = "('" . implode("'), ('", $_REQUEST['field_name']) . "')";

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year) VALUES $newdata");
```