# I want to add multiple values to the mysql data base

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Database

```
table: "country" 
coloums:"id_country,country_name"
```

i have only one text feild:

```
Country: <input type=text name="country_name" >
$conn->query("insert into country");
```

i want to fill this feild with

> "india,australia,canada,etc."

from the above line the **(,)** has to treat like new value.!
so it has to store in db with **id_country** increment..

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It'll make your data hard to use later and is far from good database design.

Comment: can you suggest any best way to add multiple values..@JayBlanchard

Comment: why it is bad @JayBlanchard  . he said  `from the above line the (,) has to treat like new value.!` so it will become like 1,India  2,Australia  etc

Comment: exactly @Anant i am looking for that.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Comment: Are you exploding this Value afterwards? Then you should Implode it with PHP.

Comment: I think the question wasn't explained properly; that's why there's confusion @Anant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$data = "india,australia,canada";
$exploded_data = explode(',',$data);
$data_to_insert = "('".implode("','",$exploded_data)."')";

echo $data_to_insert;
```

Output:-

https://eval.in/636118

and

https://eval.in/636131

Note:- Your `id_country` column must be ***`Auto-incremented primary key`.***

If so then just one query:-

`"INSERT INTO country (country_name)  VALUES ".$data_to_insert;`

Or

`"INSERT INTO country (country_name)  VALUES $data_to_insert";`

will do every-thing

***Better to do this with `prepared statements`.***

Answer (score 2):

Best would be to use PHP's `explode()` function on the input text, using `", "` as a delimiter, and then adding each country in the resulting array to your database via a foreach loop.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you, but I can explain you, EXPLODE. It'll return an array of strings.

```
$values = "value1, value2";
$explode = explode(",", $values);
```

You can continue with the following after that;

```
$explode[0];
$explode[1];
```

Comment: upto explode ok how to store data..?

Comment: When you want to store your data in 1 Value, how do you let the user seperate these values? With a space or a `,` ? You could Implode it then

Answer (score 2):

```
$countries = ['india','australia','canada']

foreach ($countries as $country) {
     // Run/build you sql query
}
```

SQL example query

```
INSERT INTO `country` (`country_name`)
VALUES ('india');
```

Answer (score 2):

To process the posted string firstly ensure the variable is actually set and passes rudimentary tests and use explode to generate an array containing the country names. Using `mysqli` and `prepared statements` allows you to construct the sql statement once, bind the necessary parameter(s) and variables once but execute multiple times very quickly.

```
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'xxx'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx';
$dbname =   'xxx';
$db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

/* make sure the posted variable isn't empty */
$countries=!empty( $_POST['country_name'] ) && stristr( $_POST['country_name'], ',' ) ? $_POST['country_name'] : false;
if( $countries ){

    /* explode the string to create the array */
    $countries=explode(',',$countries);

    /* construct sql statement for use as a prepared statement */
    $sql='insert into `country` set `country_name`=?';

    /* prepare the statement object */
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

    /* bind the param to the variable */
    $stmt->bind_param( 's', $country );

    /* iterate through all countries from POSTed string and execute the statement */
    foreach( $countries as $country ){
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

$stmt->close();
$db->close();
```