# Mysql transactions VS multiple insert / update

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I use PHP with Mysql. I care about performance and stability and that's why I now use multiple inserts / updates in one single SQL query (which is generated by PHP). With that I insert / update 1000 rows. It takes about 6 seconds.

**Kind of like this but larger:**

[Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

I've read about transactions which is meant to speed up where multiple SQL queries are added to a kind of buffer (I guess) and then all is executed.

Which method should I use in terms of performance and stability? Pros and cons?

Comment: Not having transactions: Pros, higher concurrency; cons, lack of data integrity. Having trans: Pros, data integrity; cons, lower concurrency

Comment: @Drew Alright, what would you choose?

Comment: You're only as good as the quality of your data. What good is *performance* if you perform your data into the trash can. One aims to  avoid deadlocks, lock, and resource starvation while also honoring higher priority tasks. To prevent or resolve the problem by breaking the symmetry of locks and this varies by implementation.