# Running an SQL query multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run this query 100 times to input data into my MySQL database. ID auto increments. Not concerned about incrementing the table Name column. Just need to fill the database. What is the best way to go about this without having to copy/paste 100 times?

```
"INSERT INTO `tables`(id, name, assigned_seating, open_seating, position) VALUES ('', 'Table 1', 0, 1, '')";
```

Comment: use a for loop?

Comment: can be done in one query, dont need 100, give me a mo to write that

Comment: You can do it in eight queries total if you follow that with 7 `INSERT....SELECT`s ... though technically you end up with 128 rows then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone sees this in the future, this is the best answer

```
public function addbatch()
{
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
  {
    $tableName = "Table " . $i;
    $q = "INSERT INTO `tables`(id, name, cap, assigned_seating, open_seating, position) VALUES ('', '".$tableName."', 10, 0, 1, '')";
    $this->db->query($q);
  }
}
```

call function once. Make sure to delete when done though!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an existing table with at least 100 rows. I will use `information_schema.columns` as example:

```sql
INSERT INTO `tables`(id, name, assigned_seating, open_seating, position)
    SELECT null, 'Table 1', 0, 1, ''
    FROM information_schema.columns
    LIMIT 100;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/DMSC23853

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Batch insert:

```
insert into Table
(column1, column2)
    VALUES
      ('value 1', 'value2') ,
      ('value3', 'value4')
```

You can do as many rows as you want as long as you separate them by comas.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $vals='';
 for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $vals.="('Table 1', 0, 1, ''),";
 }
 $vals=rtrim($vals,',');

 mysqli_query($dbh, 'INSERT INTO `tables`(name, assigned_seating, open_seating, position) VALUES ' . $vals);
```

assumed id was auto incremented so just leave it out of the query

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `multipleInsert` $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `multipleInsert`(in n int)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE cont int default 0;
    WHILE cont  < n DO
    INSERT INTO `tables`(id, name, assigned_seating, open_seating, position) VALUES ('', 'Table 1', 0, 1, '');
    set cont  = cont  + 1;
    end while;
    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Call Procedure:

```
call multipleInsert(100);
```