# How to insert many values very simply for mysql?

Tags: mysql, insert

Good afternoon,
How to write sql query to insert below 8 values very simply for mysql?

```
id name 
5 aaa.jpg
6 bbb.jpg
7 ccc.jpg
8 ddd.jpg
9 eee.jpg
10 fff.jpg
11 ggg.jpg
12 zzz.jpg
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Add a few quotes around those things, some commas, and a sprinkling of bracekets and you're basically there.

Comment: You have to insert like Cartesian products.

Answer (score 1):

You just use `INSERT INTO` followed by the table you want to insert it into, then specify the column.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Images (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'aaa.jpg');
```

or for inserting multiple values at once:

```
INSERT INTO Images (id, name)
VALUES (5, 'aaa.jpg'), (6, 'bbb.jpg'), (7, ccc.jpg);
```

And so on and so forth, you get the idea.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma separated groups for multiple `INSERT`s, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (5, 'aaa.jpg'), (6, 'bbb.jpg');
```