# Inserting into a table in mysql using query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table called "abcd" with 3 attributes, so now I'm trying to insert some values into this table I created.

I found that to insert a value you do something like this

```
INSERT INTO abcd
VALUES (value1,value2,value3);
```

So this works fine but what if I have multiple things to enter, is there a way to easily insert multiple entries into a table that does something like the code below?

```
INSERT INTO abcd
VALUES (value1,value2,value3);
INSERT INTO abcd
VALUES (val1,val2,val3);
INSERT INTO abcd
VALUES (v1,v2,v3);
INSERT INTO abcd
VALUES (1,2,3);
```

Do I really need to do "insert into abcd" for every single line I need to insert?

Comment: this question has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO abcd
VALUES 
(value1, value2, value3),
(val1, val2, val3),
(v1, v2, v3),
(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `values` lists:

```
INSERT INTO abcd
    VALUES (value1, value2, value3),
           (val1, val2, val3),
           (v1, v2, v3),
           (1, 2, 3);
```

I should note that if there is an error -- say an invalid foreign key reference, or a trigger that returns an error, or a unique constraint violation -- then nothing will be inserted at all.  That is, this statement is all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you can repeat the `values` part of the statement like

```
insert into abcd values(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)
```

as many times as required