# fastested way to insert 70 milions records from xml to mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have wrote a java code to parse xml file using jaxb and then insert the data from xml file to my sql. The code does insertion to different 20 tables based on the xml tags.
My problem is that my code is running for last 3 days and it could insert 5 millions record to my sql data base!
In this way I need to wait a month to finish the job..
Can you give me some hint how can I make my code efficient?

Comment: Are you inserting one record at a time? MySQL supports multi-insert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Comment: Do you really need the queries in a XML format? Can't you have another format (like plain SQL)?

Comment: @weston I guess even a multi-insert (or batch insert) wouldn't be suitable here due to the amount of data. The internal cache for a potencial rollback wouldn't be amused. Using a external way, like "Load Data" from the answer, would be more suitable.

Comment: @weston cool. but still need to read from xml file and store in a java structure then do multiple insertion. So i think java can not store 50 milion

Comment: A Java structure? Time to show your code I think.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports 'LOAD DATA' command and CSV format. So converting your XMLs into prepared CSV and then load by mysql abilities will be fastest solution:

[How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)