# MySQL - Add some of the same record

Tags: php, mysql

I want add record to MySQL database:

```
$server1 = $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO storages SET storages_id = '$local->storages_id', storages_orders_date = NOW()");
```

And I must add 10 this same records to database. I can make PHP loop (for) but I want make this in one query like (10 row is a example):

```
$server1 = $pdo->exec("INSERT X 10 INTO storages SET storages_id = '$local->storages_id', storages_orders_date = NOW()");
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying, but its really bad practice. You NEVER want to have multiple records in the same database. Thats totally useless. May you can describe what you're trying and we can tell you a better method.

Comment: There is Syntax to so same insert *n times*

Comment: Badd practice :(

Comment: Also `insert into ... set` is no valid syntax

Comment: You can insert several values a[See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: I make warehouse and I try add parts (any part have unique number).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert as many as row using this script.

```
INSERT INTO tableName
    (column1,column2,column3,column4)
VALUES
    ('value1' , 'value2', 'value3','value4'),
    ('value1' , 'value2', 'value3','value4'),
    ('value1' , 'value2', 'value3','value4');
```

This is the feasible solution to your problem.Your examples seems kinda impossible. Its not like a `SELECT` statement where you'd specify the row you require eg `SELECT TOP 10...`.