# How to insert multiple rows into MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

I am new to MySQL (have just been using SQL Server) and I am wondering how to create multiple rows easily!

I am looking to create about 300 rows, so the methods I have found online just don't seem practical enough..

When using SQL Server, you can just use a GO statement, and then enter a number afterwards and it will run the command that many times, such as : GO 50

Is there anything as simple as this on MySQL? I have read about using a loop statement, but I cannot find any info on it?

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thanks,

-Liam.

Comment: Possible duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Repeat statement:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION CalcularSueldo ( starting_value INT )
RETURNS INT

BEGIN

   DECLARE sueldo INT;

   SET sueldo = 0;

   label1: REPEAT
     SET sueldo = sueldo + starting_value;
   UNTIL sueldo >= 10000000 
   END REPEAT label1;

   RETURN sueldo;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

It's basically a loop, where you put the condition using UNTIL. Here it is used in a function but you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Hi Nick, so where would I insert the code to insert my data? I believe that my code is along the lines of: INSERT INTO mysqltest.noderedtest (Password) VALUES "Test" - Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may prepare you data with Excel, export as CSV and import to DB by common Database Tools like DBeaver and Sql Squirrel

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/722

Answer (score 0):

Without using loop:

```
CREATE TABLE noderedtest(Password TEXT, Email TEXT);

INSERT INTO noderedtest (Password, Email)  -- storing password in clear text
                                           -- is very bad idea
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS i
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i+1
   FROM cte
   WHERE i < 300
)
SELECT 'Test', 'email@email.com'
FROM cte;

SELECT * FROM noderedtest;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo MySQL 8.0+](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4eef8a9688d609e8fe2f7f046737378)**

Comment: Hi there, I tried this code but it is giving me an error at the "WITH" part of the code. The error is - "Syntax Error: unexpected 'WITH' (with). Any ideas to why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: @LiamBroughton `SELECT @@version` and my code is for MySQL 8.0 and above