# Insert an array to the database like a separate rows

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't reached the result using answers in similar questions.

Here is my situation: 
I have a table (`users_temp`) with 1 column - `Users_id`;
And I have an array of values, for example - `$usersIds = [1,2,3,4,5]`;

I want to Insert this array to my table and create 5 new rows.
I was trying smth like that, but it doesn't work:

```
$newdata = "'" . implode("','", $usersIds) . "'";
db_query("INSERT INTO db.users_temp (user_id) VALUES ($newdata)");
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: is user_ID string data or numeric?  So your final query would be '1','2','3','4','5'  I think instead of 's you want ()'s.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql for the insert in mass format.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889087/7393478) for a multiple insert in a single query. You can put the beginning of the query in a string, then loop on your array to add the values `(value),` with concatenation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the $userIds field is safe (all INTs) then just amend your implode a touch.

```
$newdata = implode("),(", $usersIds);
db_query("INSERT INTO db.users_temp (user_id) VALUES ($newdata)");
```

You might want to add a check that the array has more than 0 elements.

Comment: elegant use of implode and special mention for the precision on the source data safety (it could be dangerous to concatenate strings that could contain unescaped characters or sql commands)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$usersIds = [1,2,3,4,5];

foreach ($usersIds as $user_id) {
  db_query("INSERT INTO db.users_temp (user_id) VALUES ($user_id)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert multiple rows in a single statement:

sql:

```
insert into users_temp (user_id)
values (?), (?), (?) [...]
```

php:

```
$userIds = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('(?),', count($userIds)), ',');
$sql = "insert into users_temp (user_id) values ($placeholders)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($userIds);
```

Your code can build up the placeholders string as above.