# inserting multiple rows into mysql inside web application

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Users are allowed to choose a list of songs and add them to a playlist. there is a bridge table for the relationship between songs and playlists.

when the user assigns songs to a playlist, the application receives a list of the the song IDs and the playlist ID. the number of rows inserted into the bridge table is the same as the number of songs.

i can either call the query for each song (which seems inefficient, but usable) or i can formulate the query to insert all the data at once. my question is regarding formulating the query.

i have a list of song ids

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,]
```

and a playlist id (just an int).

my sequelize query looks like this:

```
sequelize.query(
        `INSERT INTO songsplaylistsbridge (song, playlist)
        VALUES ($1, $2);`, {
          bind: [songs, playlist]
        }
      )
```

i understand from [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql) how the query should look, but i can't come up with a for-loop which will generate a usable object.

i have a list which looks like

```
['(1, 43)', '(2, 43)', '(3, 43)', '(4, 43)']
```

...etc. how do i insert these values into the query appropriately? thank you

Comment: If you have a list like that in a variable named, say, `songlist`, you can just do `songlist.join(',')` to get that same list as a single comma-delimited list, like `"(1, 43),(2,43),..."`. You can see the answer to [Easy way to turn JavaScript array into comma-separated list?](//stackoverflow.com/q/201724). I can't tell you how to use that in your sequelize statement; I've never used it.

Comment: MySQL allows insert many rows into table by one query
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889087/7241757](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889087/7241757)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `bind`, just compose the query text:

```js
var values = ['(1, 43)', '(2, 43)', '(3, 43)', '(4, 43)'];
var query = "INSERT INTO songsplaylistsbridge (song, playlist) VALUES " + values.join(", ");
console.log(query);
```

Comment: this is where my lack of fundamentals shines so brightly, thank you sir.