# Insert array into SQL database

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an array of data that I would like to insert into my SQL database (table), I then want to be able to fetch it as an array in a separate file. I have no idea how to put it in as an array and get it back out as an array

This is for a contract, I have already tried inserting it as a string and then getting it out as an array but that doesn't work

```
$added = $_POST['added']; // this is the array

foreach ($added as $addedArr){

                    }
```

and I tried inserting `$addedArr`

That's the only code i can really show, I'm very stuck.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: I may have misread. If you intend to save an array to a single cell in a database, you can utilize serialize / [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn your array into a string and save it. Then you can load  the data later and [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it or [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it.

Comment: You should probably create a child table in your database and then relate it back to the parent table with a foreign key constraint. Then you add each record as a new row in the child table using a foreach loop. This will save you a lot of headaches when reading the data later and keep your database in normal form.

Comment: This certainly depends on what kind of data @tzcoding is trying to store, I think we need clarification for any more specific recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ([guide](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)), for example, you could execute a query with an array, giving you a few options.

One such option would be to [execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) numerous queries with each sub-array, such as:

```
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  $query = $database->prepare('SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < ? AND color = ?');
  $query->execute($array);
}
```

Another option would be to flatten out your array and do a [multi line query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889087/1843510) like so:

```
$flat_array = []; //The array that will contain all the values of the main array of data
$query = 'insert into fruit (name, color, calories) values '; //Build the base query
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  $query .= '(?, ?, ?),'; //Add in binding points to the query
  foreach ($array as $value) $flat_array[] = $value; //Add each value of each sub-array to to the top level of the new array
}
$query = $database->prepare(substr($query, 0, -1)); //Prepare the query, after removing the last comma
$query->execute($flat_array); //Execute the query with the new, flat array of values
```

You would then be able to pull out the data into an associative array later on with that [same guide](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach).