# Inserting multiple rows in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php

I have a script where I want to insert all rows in a single statement, but I don't know how to do that.

Here's the code I have so far. This only inserts one row. How can I insert multiple rows?

```php
<?php
include ('includes/config.php');

if (strlen($_SESSION['alogin']) == 0) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location ='adminlogin.php'; </script>";
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $batchname = $_POST['batchname'];
        $studentid = $_POST['studentid'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO  tblattendance(Date,BatchName,StudentId,Status) VALUES(CURDATE(),:batchname,:studentid,:status)";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':batchname', $batchname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':studentid', $studentid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        if ($lastInsertId) {
            $msg = "Attendance Added successfully";
        } else {
            $error = "Something went wrong. Please try again";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
You can search your question on the web, this question is asked several times and answered
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889087/1007945

Comment: Thanks sir for this comment