# Why aren't my columns displaying the correct names and the right amount of characters?

Tags: sql

I created my table:
[image]End result:

[image]Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to create a table showing the employee information, but when I used the "insert" command only the information for the second employee appears. Also, the column names are missing and the numbers are incorrect.

*Edit*
Apologies about the images. I made some updates, but I am still having an issue with the column names and my first row not appearing.

```
Create table biscoe6
("EmployeeID" "varchar"(11),
"SSN" "varchar"(11),
"fName" "varchar"(12),
"lName" "varchar"(12),
"Position" "varchar"(12),
"Salary" number(10, 2),
"PhoneNum" "char"(12)); 

insert into biscoe6 ("EmployeeID", "SSN", "fName", "lName", "Position", "Salary", "PhoneNum")
values (null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
values (100, '111-11-0607', 'John', 'Smith', 'Manager', 35000.75, '800-350-0000');
values (200, '333-22-0607', 'John', 'Jones', 'Associate', 25000.00, '202-666-0000');
values (300, '444-444-0607', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'Manager', 46500.00, '303-999-0000');
values (400, '111-11-2102', 'Randy', 'Johnson', 'Intern', 36900.00, '205-654-0000');
```

Comment: What is your SQL _version_ (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: I honestly I am not sure. I am a student and this is part of my first assignment. We were instructed to use www.sqlcourse.com as a SQL interpreter.

Comment: Try to change the online IDE , because if you are not running on your local system then it cause such type of errors on online IDE .Try to use W3School or any other .

Comment: Any column that has the type `char` or `varchar` needs to be surrounded by `''`, in the same way that names are quoted. Otherwise, the `SSN` and `PhoneNum` values are storing the literal subtraction of the 3 numbers, which causes the `numbers are incorrect`. Also, post those two code example as text instead of images using the `{}` icon on the editor toolbar, so that others can copy/past your code to assist.

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: There might be a problem with the online tool you are using, not always reliable to use when learning.

I think you need to review what is valid SQL

Insert statement is usually

`INSERT INTO {TABLE} (Columns) VALUES (values)`

So for each insert statement you need to start with INSERT and followed by Values.

`INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (values);

INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (values);`


You may also find your SSN definition of `varchar(11)` is not enough for a value such as "444-444-0607"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first insert-values is working, but the second values does not have a corresponding insert and it is being treated as a simple select-values. The results you see is from the sole values.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a basic mistake,values must be one time and comma separated values. try this

```
insert into biscoe6 ("EmployeeID", "SSN", "fName", "lName", "Position", "Salary", "PhoneNum") 
    values 
    (100, '111-11-0607', 'John', 'Smith', 'Manager', 35000.75, '800-350-0000'),
    (200, '333-22-0607', 'John', 'Jones', 'Associate', 25000.00, '202-666-0000'), 
    (300, '444-444-0607', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'Manager', 46500.00, '303-999-0000'), 
    (400, '111-11-2102', 'Randy', 'Johnson', 'Intern', 36900.00, '205-654-0000');
```