# Merge, when matched insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to perform constructive merge in Oracle i.e. if a matching record is found in the source table, a new record with current timestamp should be added to the destination table.

How do I do this using merge in Oracle? Below is my code which gives a "missing keyword" error.

```
merge into studLoad sl
using student s
on(s.studID=sl.studID)
when matched
then
insert(sl.studID,sl.studName)
values(s.studID||'abc',s.studName)
when not matched
then
insert(sl.studID,sl.studName)
values(s.studID,s.studName);
```

Also, I dont know how to add current timestamp along with the `studName`. Any suggestions for the same would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be done with a merge (as Justin said) but with two inserts. **Just one row** for each match (also with duplicate matchings as you said in the comment) and then all the rows from student. This can be done in the following way.

```
insert into studLoad ( studID, studName, <<timestamp column>> )
select studID, studName, systimestamp
from student
where studId in (
        selct studId
        from studLoad
    )
/
insert into studLoad (studID, studName)
select studID, studName
from student
/
```

And don't invert this execution order!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to insert a new row whether or not there is a match, it wouldn't make sense to use a `MERGE`.  Simply do an `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO student( studID, studName, <<timestamp column>> )
  SELECT (CASE WHEN s.studId IS NOT NULL -- If there is a match
               THEN <<student ID sequence>>.nextval
               ELSE sl.studID
           END), 
         studName, 
         (CASE WHEN s.studId IS NOT NULL -- If there is a match
               THEN systimestamp
               ELSE NULL
           END)
    FROM studLoad sl
         LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON (sl.studID = s.studId)
```

Note that I'm assuming that your `student` table actually has a column to store the current timestamp-- use that column name in place of `<<timestamp column>>` in the SQL statement above.

Comment: but i wish to check the entire source table and check which all records are updated and add new entries for the updated records into the target table...so how do i use single insert to do that? i have to use merge.

Comment: @z22 - Sorry, I don't understand.  What is different about the case where there is a match and the case where there is no match?  In the question you posted, you're doing an `INSERT` in both cases.

Comment: this is the case: if record doesnt exist-insert it, if it exists, keep it as it is and insert a new record along with the timestamp and a new surrogate key-hope i made myself clear this time.

Comment: @z22 - Sorry, I still don't understand.  If the row exists, you want to insert a new row.  If the row doesn't exist, you want to insert a new row.  What is different about the row you insert when there is a match and the row you insert when there is no match?  Are you saying that you only want to populate the timestamp column of the new row if there is a match?

Comment: okay when i insert when there is not a match then i insert whole record as it is along with its key, but when i insert when there is a match then i insert whole record as it is EXCEPT the key-i generate a surrogate key and insert it. Plus if the record matches then i also add a timestamp, now you got the difference or should i once again try to explain? :)

Comment: @z22 - OK.  Is there a sequence that is used to generate the new surrogate key?  And you do not want to populate the timestamp column in the new row if there is no match?

Comment: @z22 - OK, then I think you still want an `INSERT` but you want to join the `student` and `studLoad` tables in your `SELECT`.  Updated my answer