# Not understanding cursor

Tags: plsql

The problem i'm dealing with is follow :

I have a table students with name and surname. I create a new table Students2, and i want to fill this table with names and surnames from the first table with cursor.

I make the declare of the cursor, the select part, but in the **LOOP PART**, i don't understand how you fetch the values. For example, if I do:

```
  FETCH name_surname INTO Students2.name,Students2.surname
```

it doesn't work, and I don't know how to fix it.

In name_surname I mention, I Selected the name and surname from the first table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT and UPDATE a record using cursors in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921889/insert-and-update-a-record-using-cursors-in-oracle)

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Why must you do this using a cursor? Plain SQL would be simpler. Also, define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

```
"Declare cursor c1 is select * from student2;
Begin
For i in c1 loop
Dbms_output.put_line(i.fname||','||i.lanme);
End loop;
End;"
```