# How can I insert multiple row into oracle database using one insert statement?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to do multi-row insert in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle)

I have this insert statement

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
('val1', 'val2'),
('aa',   'cc'),
('ww',   'dd');
```

and I got this error 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @njk: that won't help. Oracle simply does not support this syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Learned something new.

Answer (score 23):

you are using oracle, try this

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO mytable ("id", "name")
         VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
    INTO mytable ("id", "name")
         VALUES ('aa', 'cc')
    INTO mytable ("id", "name")
         VALUES  ('ww', 'dd')
SELECT * FROM dual  ;
```

or simple

```
INSERT INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
INSERT INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('aa', 'cc');
INSERT INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('ww', 'dd');
```

Comment: so the answer would be no.