# Multiple insert SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, identity-column, oracle12c

How do you do multiple insert with SQL in Oracle 12c when you have an identity column?

```
INSERT ALL
INTO Table1 (Column2) Values (1)
INTO Table1 (Column2) Values (2)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

where Table1 has column1 as an identity, will set the identity column to have the same value which violates the primary key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  Table1Id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  column2 VARCHAR2(255),
  column3 NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (Table1Id)
);

INSERT ALL
  INTO Table1 (column2, column3) VALUES ('a', '1')
  INTO Table1 (column2, column3) VALUES ('b', '2')
SELECT * FROM dual;

--SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated
```

What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. It is a problem with the way Oracle is using the internal sequence with Insert All statement. I have edited my answer. You can see the demo.

Comment: I have added few more test cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** Added two test cases, and a possible workaround.

Though `Insert` statement and `insert all` statement are practically the same conventional insert statement. But when it comes to sequences, they work differently.

**Test case 1 : Identity columns**

```
SQL> DROP TABLE table1 PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  2    Table1Id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  3    column3 NUMBER,
  4    PRIMARY KEY (Table1Id)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO Table1 (column3) VALUES ('1')
  3    INTO Table1 (column3) VALUES ('2')
  4  SELECT * FROM dual;
INSERT ALL
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.SYS_C0010439) violated


SQL>
```

Let's see what's actually happening under the hood -

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  2    Table1Id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  3    column3 NUMBER,
  4    CONSTRAINT A UNIQUE (Table1Id)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO Table1 (column3) VALUES (1)
  3    INTO Table1 (column3) VALUES (2)
  4  SELECT * FROM dual;
INSERT ALL
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.A) violated


SQL> SELECT * FROM table1;

no rows selected

SQL> ALTER TABLE table1
  2  DISABLE CONSTRAINT a;

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO Table1 (column3) VALUES (1)
  3    INTO Table1 (column3) VALUES (2)
  4  SELECT * FROM dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM table1;

  TABLE1ID    COLUMN3
---------- ----------
         2          1
         2          2

SQL>
```

So, the sequence progressed to `nextval` however there was an unique constraint violation the first time we did an Insert All. Next, we **disabled the unique constraint**, and the subsequent Insert All reveals that the sequence did not progress to nextval, rather it attempted to **insert duplicate keys**.

Though the issue doesn't occur with a `INSERT-INTO-SELECT` statement.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO table1(column3) SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=5;

5 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM table1;

  TABLE1ID    COLUMN3
---------- ----------
         2          1
         3          2
         4          3
         5          4
         6          5

SQL>
```

Surprisingly, as per the metadata, the sequence is supposed to proceed to nextval automatically, however it doesn't happen with an Insert All statement.

```
SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
  2    IDENTITY_COLUMN,
  3    DATA_DEFAULT
  4  FROM user_tab_cols
  5  WHERE table_name   ='TABLE1'
  6  AND IDENTITY_COLUMN='YES';

COLUMN_NAME     IDENTITY_COLUMN DATA_DEFAULT
--------------- --------------- ------------------------------
TABLE1ID        YES             "LALIT"."ISEQ$$_94458".nextval

SQL>
```

**Test Case 2 : Using a sequence explicitly**

The **INSERT ALL** would work the same way whether an identity column is used or an **explicit sequence** is used.

```
SQL> DROP SEQUENCE s;

Sequence dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE s;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> DROP TABLE t PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (
  2    ID NUMBER,
  3    text VARCHAR2(50),
  4    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'a')
  3    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'b')
  4    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'c')
  5    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'd')
  6  SELECT * FROM dual;
INSERT ALL
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.ID_PK) violated


SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t
  2    DISABLE CONSTRAINT id_pk;

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'a')
  3    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'b')
  4    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'c')
  5    INTO t VALUES (s.nextval, 'd')
  6  SELECT * FROM dual;

4 rows created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

        ID TEXT
---------- ----------------------------------------
         2 a
         2 b
         2 c
         2 d

SQL>
```

**Possible workaround - Using a ROW LEVEL trigger**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_trg
  2      BEFORE INSERT ON t
  3      FOR EACH ROW
  4      WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
  5      BEGIN
  6        SELECT s.NEXTVAL
  7        INTO   :new.id
  8        FROM   dual;
  9      END;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL> truncate table t;

Table truncated.

SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO t (text) VALUES ('a')
  3    INTO t (text) VALUES ('b')
  4    INTO t (text) VALUES ('c')
  5    INTO t (text) VALUES ('d')
  6  SELECT * FROM dual;

4 rows created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

        ID TEXT
---------- -------------------------
         3 a
         4 b
         5 c
         6 d

SQL>
```

Comment: What do you mean that his assumption is wrong?  I can reproduce his error on 12.1.0.2.  This looks like a pretty big problem with identity columns.

Comment: Yes correct, When I made the [test](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/) I completely missed the unique constraint.

Comment: And it is not an issue only with Identity column, but the way `Insert All` works. Sequence is fetched only once. Adding the explanation to the answer. The only workaround I see is the old trigger based approach. The row level trigger would increment the sequence for each row inserted.

Comment: @LalitKumarB In answer it was said "Though the issue doesn't occur with a INSERT-INTO-SELECT statement.", but when I tried the statment fails as we cant use a `sequnce.nextval` as it is prohibited in `union`of `select`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a workaround using the `UNION ALL` method instead of the `INSERT ALL` method.  For some reason the data must be wrapped in a `select * from (...)` or it will generate the error `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("JHELLER"."TABLE1"."TABLE1ID")`.

```
insert into table1(column2, column3)
select *
from
(
    select 'a', '1' from dual union all
    select 'b', '2' from dual
);
```