# Populate Oracle table with test data for PL/SQL generator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to write PL/SQL generator of dummy data (e.g. names as combination of first and last most popular names) for Oracle 12c.

So I need to populate names and surnames tables with source data first.

I cannot use *sqlldr* and all I have access to is *SQL*Plus* and *SQLDeveloper*.

I can populate my source tables with lots of individual insert statements like:

```sql
INSERT INTO names(id, name) VALUES(1, 'Oliver');
INSERT INTO names(id, name) VALUES(2, 'Jack');
⋮
INSERT INTO names(id, name) VALUES(50, 'Aaron');
```

I wonder whether there are any other (perhaps more elegant) options.

---

#### Edit:

I was hitting another issue coming from a fact that value of generated identity column is not incremented during `INSERT ALL`. There is a nice workaround described in this [related answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28556043/2948889).

Comment: You could use [`INSERT ALL`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php)

Comment: @GurV like this?    
`INSERT ALL
  INTO names (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Oliver’)
  INTO names (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Jack’)
  ⋮
  INTO names (id, name) VALUES (50, 'Aaron’)
SELECT * FROM dual;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in oracle:

```
INSERT INTO names(id, name)
select 1, 'Oliver' from dual union all
select 2, 'Jack' from dual union all
. . .
```

Then there is INSERT ALL:

```
INSERT ALL 
  INTO names (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Oliver')
  INTO names (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Jack')
select * from dual;
```

I like the first one better.

Comment: How do I use first form with table with generated id (like `create table names( id number generated always as identity primary key, name varchar2(50) not null);` I am getting _ORA-01400 cannot insert NULL into_

Comment: You can't insert values into `generated always` column. Use `insert into names(name) select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual`. The id will be generated automatically

Comment: You can, of course. Just don't put the value for it in your insert. the value is **generated** by Oracle

Comment: I must be missing something hiding in plain sight. `INSERT INTO names(name) select 'Oliver' from dual union select 'Jack' from dual;` ends with ORA-01400

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out http://plsql.ninja/npg/package/random_ninja. Morten Egan has been building a very interesting library of utilities and his random_ninja package will generate all sorts of data for you.