# How to batch insert multiple rows at once into a table with an auto incremented id field in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c. I have a table with an auto increment column, `pk_id`. For a single row insert I do this:

```
insert into mytable (colA, colB) values (1,2);
```

It works. The primary key column `pk_id` is auto generated.I found how to insert multiple rows in one go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle). So I tried this to do batch insert:

```
insert all
    into mytable (colA, colB) values (2,4) 
    into mytable (colA, colB) values (3,6) 
    into mytable (colA, colB) values (4,8) 
    into mytable (colA, colB) values (5,10) 
select 1 from dual;
```

But it is showing this error:

```
An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key
```

How can I do batch insert?

EDIT: The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
(
  PK_ID NUMBER(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL 
, COLA NUMBER(8) NOT NULL 
, COLB NUMBER(8) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT MYTABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    PK_ID 
  )
  ENABLE 
);
```

Comment: Oracle has sequences, not auto increment columns.  Can you show your table definition?

Comment: Also: Your syntax does not match the syntax of the accepted answer in the question you linked.  For example, you have more semicolons at line ends.

Comment: @WW Table definition posted. btw, I am using the syntax in the [most voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle#answer-93724), instead of the accepted one.