# SQL insert same values with different IDs in 1 query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Is it possible to insert multiple values in a table with the same data except from the primary key (`ID`)?

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO apples (name, color, quantity) 
VALUES of(txtName, txtColor, txtQuantity)
```

Is it possible to insert 50 red apples with different IDs?

```
ID(PK) |Name  | Color | Quantity
1       apple   red      1
2       apple   red      1
```

Is it possible like this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Many database systems have some kind of `identity` or auto-increment column type - but that's **highly vendor-specific**

Comment: If you set `ID` as `indentity` (for sql server, for instance). But you should tell us your DBMS.

Comment: hmm I have set the ID to auto_increment I just need to know whats the way to insert multiple rows with the same data. What I have now is 1 row inserted with the quantity column to whatever number i enter.

Comment: Then why did you tag it mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to do multi-row insert in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INSERT ALL or use the UNION ALL like this.

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO apples  (name, color, quantity) VALUES ('apple', 'red', '1')
   INTO apples  (name, color, quantity) VALUES ('apple', 'red', '1')
   INTO apples  (name, color, quantity) VALUES ('apple', 'red', '1')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

or

```
insert into apples (name, color, quantity)
select 'apple', 'red', '1' from dual
union all 
select 'apple', 'red', '1' from dual
```

Prior to Oracle 12c you can create SEQUENCE on your ID column. Also if you are using Oracle 12c then you can make your ID column as identity

```
CREATE TABLE apples(ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY);
```

Also if the sequence is not important and you just need a different/unique ID then you can use

```
CREATE TABLE apples( ID RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SEQUENCE`.

```
`CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1`
```

Then in your `INSERT` statement, use this

```
`INSERT INTO apples (id, name, color, quantity)
  VALUES(seq_name.nextval, 'apple', 'red', 1 );`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in single **SQL** statement using **CONNECT BY** clause, also known as **Row generator method**.

For example, to generate `10` rows:

```
SQL> SELECT LEVEL  ID,
  2        'apple' NAME ,
  3        'red'   color,
  4        1       quantity
  5  FROM dual
  6    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10;

        ID NAME  COLOR    QUANTITY
---------- ----- ------ ----------
         1 apple red             1
         2 apple red             1
         3 apple red             1
         4 apple red             1
         5 apple red             1
         6 apple red             1
         7 apple red             1
         8 apple red             1
         9 apple red             1
        10 apple red             1

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

You could use the above `SELECT` as `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE APPLES(PK_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,NAME VARCHAR2(100), COLOR VARCHAR2(100), QUANTITY VARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO APPLES (PK_ID, NAME, COLOR, QUANTITY)  VALUES(1, 'apple', 'red', 1 );
INSERT INTO APPLES (PK_ID, NAME, COLOR, QUANTITY)  VALUES(2, 'apple', 'red', 1 );
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Answer (score -1):

Create Table with 4 columns

then Add same set of rows with different primary key

```
INSERT INTO apples (ID,name, color, quantity) VALUES (UniqueID,txtName, txtColor, txtQuantity);
```

Comment: This won't insert multiple rows brother, I have got the same insert statement. if the txtQuantity is 50 it will just insert one row with the quantity column having a 50 value. What I need is 50 rows with the quantity of 1.