# Inserting data into Oracle table (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I already have a table built in oracle. 
Im trying to insert some data like this:

```
INSERT INTO movies_actor('name','id')  
VALUES  ('Nuno','2'),  ('Pedro','3'),  ('Jose','1');
select * from movies_actor;
```

I always get this error

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(Column1, Column2) 
VALUES('Nuno', '2');
```

In your example, it would be:

```
INSERT INTO movies_actor(name, id)  
VALUES ('Nuno','2');

INSERT INTO movies_actor(name, id)  
VALUES ('Pedro','3');

INSERT INTO movies_actor(name, id)  
VALUES ('Jose','1');

select * from movies_actor;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the single quote around your field names.

Comment: upvoted because Brandon does not enough enough reputation for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
insert into table
(field1, field2)
select value1, value2
from dual
union
select value3, value4
from dual
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert multiple records in one statement using `VALUES`. You can either use Tenzin's solution or use `INSERT ALL` :

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO movies_actor(name, id) VALUES ('Nuno', '2')
    INTO movies_actor(name, id) VALUES ('Pedro', '3')
    INTO movies_actor(name, id) VALUES ('Jose', '1')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```