# Is there an equivalent OCI-COLLECTION in php for PDO?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, collections, oracle-call-interface

I'm working with an oracle database and I need to instantiate an oracle collection in the way that oci-collection would. See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-collection.php

However, I am using PDO and I don't see anything in the php docs (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) that looks equivalent. Is there a way to use the PDO connection to call the OCI-COLLECTION functionality? Or what other solutions to this might I not be seeing...

I could instantiate an oci_connect but that seems redundant, unnecessary, and potentially wrong...

Comment: I looked at the OCI8 documentation, but I couldn't see what collections are used for.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/seliverstov-multirows-098120.html essentially what I'm after is a way to bulk insert to an oracle table rather than running 1 update statement at a time. (I'm inserting upwards to a million records at a time).

Comment: There's nothing like it in PDO, because this is very Oracle-specific, and PDO tries to be database-independent. Instead of running 1 update at a time, batch them with multiple values: `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...), (...), (...), ...`

Comment: Oracle does not accept multiple inserts in 1 statement in the same way that MySQL does :( I am not familiar with the syntax - reviewing this at the moment. perhaps it will answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle

Comment: Yeah, I guess you need to use that method for Oracle.