# Mybatis batch insert exception:ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

My project uses Springboot and Mybatis, I use batch insert grammer to save data
and I used an oracle database

```js
<sql id="site_columns">
    ID, SITE_URL, BRM_HGSSITE_ID, BRM_SITE_STATUS, BPS_HGSSITE_ID, SITE_STATUS, OP_HGSSITE_ID, BILLING_PLATFORM, BLIS_EFFECTIVE_FROM,
    BLIS_EFFECTIVE_TO, BRM_EFFECTIVE_FROM, ISSUE_TYPE, COMMENTS, CSM_FIRST_NAME, CSM_LAST_NAME, CSM_EMAIL, CREATE_TIME
</sql>
```

```js
<insert id="batchSaveVerifiedSitesFromFile" parameterType="siteSummaryInfoBean">
    INSERT INTO MR_VERIFIED_SITE_LIST(<include refid="site_columns"/>) VALUES
    <foreach collection="list" item="site" separator=",">
        (MR_VERIFIED_SITE_LIST_SEQ.nextval, #{site.webexurl}, #{site.brm_hgssiteid}, #{site.brm_sitestatus},
        #{site.bps_hgssiteid}, #{site.sitestatus},
        #{site.op_hgssiteid}, #{site.billingplatform,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{site.blis_effectiveFrom,jdbcType=DATE},
        #{site.blis_effectiveTo,jdbcType=DATE}, #{site.brm_effectiveFrom,jdbcType=DATE},
        #{site.issueType,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{site.comments,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{site.csmfirstname,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{site.csmlastname,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{site.csmemail,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        greatest(nvl(#{site.blis_effectiveTo,jdbcType=DATE},sysdate),
        nvl(#{site.brm_effectiveFrom,jdbcType=DATE},sysdate)))
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Comment: And what's the problem ?

Comment: Your error related to Oracle Database, please, provide executed query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support multi-row insert statements.

You can write an `insert into ... select ... union all select ...` statement [as seen in a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602/1062189).

This way in your `foreach` loop the separator will be `union all` and the loop body will be `select ... from dual`.

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement should be inside the foreach.

For example overwrite $sql variable in each loop in the code itself.