# How Insert Many Records In One ExecuteNonQuery Oracle Table by C#

Tags: c#, oracle

How Execute More One In Oracle Table by C#

```
"

Insert into table values (1,'A')
Insert into table values (2,'Ab')
Insert into table values (3,'Ac')
Insert into table values (4,'At')
....
"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle

Comment: `insert into MyTable(id, name) select 1, 'A' from Dual union all select 2, 'Ab' from Dual union all ...`

Comment: or run an anonymous block: `begin Insert into table values (1,'A'); Insert into table values (1,'B'); ... end;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is *vague one*. If you want a *single* query with *many* records to insert, try `insert + select` syntax:

[Best way to do multi-row insert in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle)

in your case

```
     insert into MyTable(id, name) 
            select 1, 'A'  from dual
  union all select 2, 'Ab' from dual
  union all select 3, 'Ac' from dual
  union all select 4, 'At' from dual
```

If you want to *combine* several queries, try putting them into an *anonymous block*:

```
  begin
    insert into MyTable values (1,'A');
    insert into MyTable values (2,'Ab');
    insert into MyTable values (3,'Ac');
    insert into MyTable values (4,'At');
    ...
  end;
```