# How to insert multiple values in 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, sqlplus, insert-into

How to insert multiple values in a table in oracle 11g using query?

I tried This

[image]

Comment: you have error?  show the error message  ..

Comment: It takes a simple google search : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And don´t post code as screenshots but rather inline.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following `DML` known as `INSERT ALL` statement :

```
insert all into departmentstrigger values(4,'Hello') 
           into departmentstrigger values(5,'HEy There')
           into departmentstrigger values(6,'sup')
           into departmentstrigger values(7,'Hii')
  select * from dual;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b224c/1)

For a detailed explanation you may look at : [Insert All Statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php)

Comment: @uzi I'd like to thank you but have you really tried with `from departmentstrigger` instead of `from dual`?