# Insert multiple rows in a oracle database from java using getGeneratedKeys() in one statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I already found out about the INSERT ALL syntax and it works fine as long I don't want to retrieve the inserted id values.

As an opposite to INSERT ALL syntax I could just use mutliple INSERT INTO statements in a transaction which would work but is bad for performance as stated here: [Best way to do multi-row insert in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle#comment35541561_93724).

This is my current code:

```
//Creation of INSERT INTO statement
//...    
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {"someIDColumn"});
ResultSet idResulSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
//Usage of the generated keys
```

It works for a single row but if I try the INSERT ALL syntax I get an:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>
> Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 187, Sql = INSERT ALL INTO bpos(artnr, bstnr, menge) VALUES (3, 31, 4) INTO bpos(artnr, bstnr, menge) VALUES (5, 31, 6) INTO bpos(artnr, bstnr, menge) VALUES (1, 31, 2) SELECT * FROM dual RETURNING artnr INTO :1 , OriginalSql = INSERT ALL INTO bpos(artnr, bstnr, menge) VALUES (3, 31, 4) INTO bpos(artnr, bstnr, menge) VALUES (5, 31, 6) INTO bpos(artnr, bstnr, menge) VALUES (1, 31, 2) SELECT * FROM dual RETURNING artnr INTO ?, Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Is it possible to retrieve all inserted ids after an INSERT ALL statement?

Comment: Have you tried using batch execution instead? I'm not sure if generated keys retrieval is supported for batch execution by the Oracle driver (given JDBC defines that as optional/implementation-specific), but it is likely better than generating your own query string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can tell, it is possible, but not directly (as you could do it with updates or deletes); a little *workaround* has to be used.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    type    tt_test is table of test%rowtype index by binary_integer;
  3    l_test  tt_test;
  4    l_id    sys.odcinumberlist;
  5  begin
  6    select id, name
  7      bulk collect into l_test
  8      from (select 111 id, 'Little' name from dual union all
  9            select 222 id, 'Foot'   name from dual
 10           );
 11
 12    forall i in l_test.first .. l_test.last
 13      insert into test (id, name) values (l_test(i).id, l_test(i).name)
 14      returning l_test(i).id bulk collect into l_id;
 15
 16    for i in l_id.first .. l_id.last loop
 17      dbms_output.put_line('Inserted ID = ' || l_id(i));
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /
Inserted ID = 111
Inserted ID = 222

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I don't know, though, can you use it in your (Java?) code as I don't speak that language.

Comment: This could work but you have used the INSERT INTO syntax which means that I'd have to do an insert for every row i want to insert. What I am looking for is the usage of INSERT ALL INTO ... statement (or something similar to it) mainly for performance reasons. I can imagine it can't be done because INSERT ALL INTO can insert values into different tables.

Comment: Your INSERT ALL is substituted by a combination of BULK COLLECT and FORALL (the first and the second statement in my code). As I've said, I don't think that INSERT ALL, itself, can be used with the RETURNING INTO clause.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
statement.executeBatch
```

not:

```
statement.executeUpdate
```