# Syntax error when trying to insert multiple rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to store multiple values into a table with two columns in a single command. Here is my command,

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORY
VALUES('BUS','BUSINESS'), ('CHN', 'CHILDREN'), ('COK', 'COOKING'), ('COM', 
'COMPUTER'), ('FAL', 'FAMILY LIFE'), ('FIT', 'FITNESS'), ('SEH', 'SELF HELP'), 
('LIT', 'LITERATURE');
```

I get a red underline after my first pair of values where I have the comma. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Using oracle sql developer

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/93724/2348125

Comment: Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by listing columns:

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (<colname1>, <colname2)
    VALUES ('BUS','BUSINESS'), ('CHN', 'CHILDREN'), ('COK', 'COOKING'), 
           ('COM', 'COMPUTER'), ('FAL', 'FAMILY LIFE'), ('FIT', 'FITNESS'), 
           ('SEH', 'SELF HELP'), ('LIT', 'LITERATURE');
```

Not all databases support `VALUES` with multiple rows.  So that *could* be the cause of your problem.

If you are using, say, Oracle that doesn't support this, you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (<colname1>, <colname2)
    SELECT 'BUS', 'BUSINESS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CHN', 'CHILDREN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    . . .
    SELECT 'LIT', 'LITERATURE' FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

place your column name explicitly if more column exist in your table

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORY(col1,col2)
VALUES('BUS,BUSINESS'),
('CHN', 'CHILDREN'), 
('COK', 'COOKING'),
('COM', 'COMPUTER'),
('FAL', 'FAMILY LIFE'),
('FIT', 'FITNESS'), ('SEH', 'SELF HELP'), 
('LIT', 'LITERATURE');
```