# Inserting multiple rows into table - getting error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

```
create table employee (      
  employee_id number (5), 
  first_name varchar2(100), 
  last_name varchar2(100), 
  salary number (10), 
  department_id number(5), 
  hire_date date,
  constraint pk_emp primary key (employee_id) 
  )

  insert into employee (employee_id, last_name, salary )     
   values
   (129, 'khaj', 19000),
   (130, 'ravi', 20000);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLJsd.png)

Comment: Looks like you could use a semicolon after the create table statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to do multi-row insert in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle)

Answer (score 5):

Wrong syntax.

Either

```
insert into employee (employee_id, last_name, salary)
  values (129, 'khaj', 19000);
insert into employee (employee_id, last_name, salary)
  values (130, 'ravi', 20000);
```

or

```
insert into employee (employee_id, last_name, salary)
  select 129, 'khaj', 19000 from dual union all
  select 130, 'ravi', 20000 from dual;
```

or even

```
insert all
  into employee (employee_id, last_name, salary) values (129, 'khaj', 19000)
  into employee (employee_id, last_name, salary) values (130, 'ravi', 20000)
select * from dual;
```