# Oracle Live SQL not allowing multiple row insertion

Tags: sql, oracle

Code below using sample data.

```
INSERT INTO ClientSeller VALUES
(1,'John Smith',88,1,'a',1),
(2,'Joe Smith',12,2,'b',2),
(3,'Warren ',15,2,'c',3),
(4,'Karen',69,6,'d',5),
(5,'Bob',45,6,'e',55),
(6,'Owen',65,6,'f',4),
(7,'Steve',25,5,'g',8),
(8,'Peter',24,55,'a',88),
(9,'Zoe',245,8,'b',8),
(10,'Jacky',244,2,'c',8);
```

and displays :
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 
Can any explain why this does not execute?

Comment: Look at this page and see if that helps. https://www.javatpoint.com/oracle-insert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to do multi-row insert in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I created the following table.

```
Create table ClientSeller (
    identity number(2),
    name varchar2(50),
    employeno number(2),
    otherno number(1),
    letter char(1),
    otherotherno number(1) 
)
```

Then using the code below I can insert two of your sample rows into the table. Oracle has a very clunky syntax for inserting values into a table. You absolutely need the Insert All with separate INTO tablename VALUES xxxxx for each values set and then at the end you MUST add the select 1 from DUAL. See [this example](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php) for more details.

Also, do not end your statements with the semicolon. In none of the example code provided here will you find such a character.

```
INSERT ALL
INTO ClientSeller VALUES (1,'John Smith',88,1,'a',1)
INTO ClientSeller VALUES (2,'Joe Smith',12,2,'b',2)
SELECT 1 from DUAL
```