# Oracle Array Binding vs Oracle Bulk copy

Tags: oracle, performance, .net-core, containers, bulkinsert

We have specific requirement where we need to use Bulk Insert inside docker image. Our DB is in Oracle and application designed in .Net Core 3.1. We cannot use sql loader.

Now, I am exploring which option will be better to use -

- Oracle Array Binding
- Oracle Bulk copy

In my local when I tried, I saw Array binding is faster compared to Bulk copy.
Then question remains what is the purpose of the Oracle Bulk Copy if its not faster.

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Let me throw `insert all` to the mix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/93724/5265292). I have no idea how it would compare to the options you already explored.

Comment: You should also explore external tables